# 'BlocProvider' can't be returned from method 'build'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

> error: A value of type 'BlocProvider' can't be returned from method
> 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.
> (return_of_invalid_type at [new_app] lib\src\counter_screen.dart:8)

Using `bloc: ^6.1.0` , `flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1`

[enter image description here]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWQ9w.jpg

Comment: Please submit your cubit class code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a type of `BlocProvider`, but the function `Widget build(BuildContext context)` must return a `Widget`. Just simply wrap your `BlocProvider` with a `Container` and it should work.

Comment: My issue was solved by using ( flutter pub cache repair ) , there was an error in the packages i think .